# Flask return redirect() call not redirecting user

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask site that I am running locally using flask's built-in development server (local machine).

Before I serve a page, I am running a custom security evaluation function to ensure the user is entitled to access the page.  If the user is not entitled to access the page, I am attempting to redirect the user back to the home page.  Everything in this workflow is happening as intended, except the redirect.

The user is being served the page as if they are perfectly entitled, even though the "redirect" call is still being executed.  It's most likely I'm using the redirect function incorrectly -- please enlighten me.

Here's the flask site setup:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, Markup, session, abort

def security(page_name):
    # Direct not logged in users to the login form
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        try:
            # Update user's permissions
            permissions_list = login_helpers.get_user_permissions_by_id(user_id)
            session['permissions'] = permissions_list

            if requested_page_abbreviation not in session['permissions']:
                # User does not have access -- bounce user back to home

                # I see this appear in the console
                print('Not authorized')

                # This must get executed, but the user does not get directed back home -- instead the resulting page loads as if the user has permissions
                return redirect('/home')

                # This does not execute
                # If I replace this line above the "return redirect('/home')" call, the expected "Unauthorized" page results and the 401 HTTP code is returned
                abort(401)


        except KeyError:

            # User has not yet had permissions set -- bounce user back to home to login
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/test_page', methods=['POST'])
def test_page():

    security_check('TEST')

    return render_template('test_page.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar program but I am not redirecting from the security check helper method.

what I am doing is:
I have a method that check security and return true/false based on the credentials. After getting security check result, I redirect from my route definition method. No redirection from helper method.

Example of my code is as follows and its working for me:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mymethod():
    secure = sec()
    if(secure):
        return "Secure page"
    else:
        return redirect('/login')

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return "login page"

# Do not redirect from your helper method
def sec():
    secured = False
    # Your security logic and code
    if secured:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can notice my security checker just checks the validity and tells me what to do. You can remove GET or POST from the route based on your routes requirement, I just put both there.

Comment: This did the trick.  I'm not 100% sure why, but Flask seems to not respect the redirect() call if it isn't a part of an @app.route() function.  I'm not sure if that's the right way to summarize what's happening, but from an observer's perspective that's exactly what's happening.

I restructured the call to perform the redirect within the test_page() function (after calling into the security module). It'll be a little cumbersome as I'll have to write that same logic into every page rather than utilizing a pythonic single function to redirect upon failed authorization, but hey - it works! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should consider using  -> [request hooks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)